# Vector of strings comparison C++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, vector, while-loop

I am writing a code about input strings, then compare them with other elements in the vector and, if there's a positive match, don't put them into. I wrote this:

```
    // NamePair.cpp : definisce il punto di ingresso dell'applicazione console.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <vector>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<string> names;
    vector<int> scores;
    string name = "0";
    int score = 0;
    int error = 0;
    int n = 0;

    cout << "Type a name and a score: " << endl;

    while (cin >> name >> score) {
        ++n;
        cout << "This is # " << n << " name you typed." << endl;
        if (n >= 2) {
            for (int i : scores) {
                if (names[i] == name) {
                    cout << "You have already typed this name dude!" << endl;
                }
                else if (name != "NoName") {
                    names.push_back(name);
                    scores.push_back(score);
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); ++i) {
        cout << names[i] << "\t" << scores[i] << endl;
    }

    keep_window_open();

    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that when I am trying to run the program it works but it seems to be stuck at a point where I continuously add names and scores but it doesn't do anything apparently (neither shows a warning message nor stops if "NoName" string is typed). I can't figure out why! I have tried to re-write it all but with the same result...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checking whether name exists in vector is wrong. Change

```
if (names[i] == name) {
```

to

```
if ((std::find(names.begin(), names.end(), name) != names.end()) {
```

Also, it looks like the `for (int i : scores)` loop is unnecessary here.

An `std::map` would be best suitable here. This code snippet will help you

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, int> data;
    string name;
    int score;
    for (int n = 0; cin >> name >> score; ++n) {
        if (name != "NoName" || !data.count(name))
            data[name] = score;
    }
    for (auto & i : data)
        cout << i.first << " " << i.second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/j3Gkiw

Comment: I don't know what you mean with std::map , unfortunately I am a newbie!
But when I type the second name it says I have typed a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake! Now it works perfectly... :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in your for loop.

You try to push new elements into your vector inside the loop that iterates the vector. The vector starts out empty, so the program will never enter the loop and you will never actually push any elements into the vectors.